# How many people has John Wick killed?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

Me and my dad have a bet going for how many people John Wick has killed. My father bet that, between John Wick 1 and 2, John has killed over 150 people.

Is he right?

**How many people has John Wick killed between both movies?**

Comment: Watch it again and start counting.

Comment: I don't know how this can be answered. There's no way to know how many of the people he shot or stabbed or punched died.

Comment: Why need to roll back to the original question? Should't this need to update the question?

Comment: @kit We're not going to update this question whenever a new film gets released (and thereby invalidate all the existing answers). It's unfortunate that the question is incomplete with the release of a new film now, but it's still better than the alternative of an ever-evolving question.

Comment: Alright, I get the point...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He killed a total of 204 people. 76 in the first movie. 128 in the second.
Here are the videos:

John Wick -

John Wick: Chapter 2 -

[image: John Wick 2 infographic]

Answer (score 4):

- In *John Wick*, he kills 77 people
- In *John Wick: Chapter 2*, he kills 128 people.
- and in *John Wick: Chapter 3 - Parabellum*, he ends up taking out 94 people.

So, the total number of kills comes to 299.